# How to parse files for a string, search backwards for another string and export the full line where that string occurs to a file

Tags: perl

I am trying to search multiple time stamp based log files for a matching phrase "##Unable to connect", then search backwards (these are time stamped log files) until I find "##Row" and export that full line of text to a file.

I need to search 100's of log files that indicate a disconnect error (##unable to connect" and find the locations (##row...." where the disconnects are occurring to analyze the data for locations trends where the disconnects are happening.

Comment: You should probably show what you've tried so far so that others can fill in the blanks rather than asking people to write the full script themselves.

Comment: Why not keep track of the most recent Row line so you don't have to go backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Just record the most recently encountered `##Row` line.

```
my $row;
while (<>) {
   $row = $_  if /##Row/;
   print $row if /##Unable to connect/;
}
```